# TFS 2018 missing Path Filter in build trigger

Tags: tfs, tfs-2018

I am using TFS2018 and by some reason in builds fetched from "External git" I cannot set "Path Filters" trigger. Only "Branch filters" are available. Some one know why?
Thanks.

Comment: The most likely cause is that it's not a supported feature in TFS2018. If you want to have access to the most current features, you need to either use a self-updating cloud hosted service or do regular upgrades to new versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use path filter when we choose Azure Repos, GitHub or Bitbucket cloud as source. However, currently we cannot use path filter when the source is "External git".

If you would like that feature, please use [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) and create a request for this feature. The product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.